# How to run jar file from Jenkins to EC2 remote server

Tags: linux, remote, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I'm trying to run a jar file by execute shell on jenkins server to ec2 server with the following command:

```
ssh -i [mykey] [username]@[Ip address of the host]  java  -jar [jarname].jar'
```

but keep getting an error message:

> "Error: Unable to access jar file Mycode.jar"

When I try to run `java -jar Mycode.jar` directly on the machine it works fine, just when I'm when it's done remotely, it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute through ssh:

```
ssh remote@machine.com 'java -jar hellofile.jar'
```

and you will see the result in the terminal